# when i'm recalling saved videos from cache memory, app going to hang and scrolling slow how to resolved it.?

Tags: android

I'm fetching all videos and folder from internal and external storage memory, but i cannot save in android cache memory, when i'm going to to save all external and internal folder/videos in android cache and get all videos from cache memory so slow scrolling and app response going to hanged ?

here is my screen short of code.
[image]

Getting videos from this line of codes
when i'm comment 
this line app working fine

songs.setData(id);

[image]

Comment: anyone can helpm me please?